# Adjust UICollectionViewCells Size for 4/3.5 inches screens

Tags: ios, iphone, uicollectionview, autolayout, uicollectionviewcell

I'm trying the UICollectionView feature (it's a very nice one...). One thing is not clear - how to support both 4 and 3.5 inches screens in relation to the UICollectionViewCells size. I want to have the gaps between the edges and between cells remain the same, and have the cell size change according to the device.

How should I approach this?

Answer (score 1):

You should first subclass `UICollectionViewFlowLayout`. Some implementation can be like this in the header file:

```
@interface CustomCollectionViewLayout : UICollectionViewFlowLayout

@end
```

And the implementation file:

```
@implementation CustomCollectionViewLayout

-(id) init
{
    if(self = [super init])
    {
        BOOL is4Inch = ([[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.height == 568.0);
        CGSize ItemSize = is4Inch ? CGSizeMake(150, 120) : CGSizeMake(90, 72);
        [self setItemSize:ItemSize];
        [self setMinimumInteritemSpacing:10.0];
        [self setMinimumLineSpacing:10.0];
        [self setScrollDirection:UICollectionViewScrollDirectionVertical];
        [self setHeaderReferenceSize:CGSizeMake(0, 5)];
        [self setFooterReferenceSize:CGSizeMake(0, 20)];
        [self setSectionInset:UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 10, 0, 10)];
    }

    return self;
}

@end
```

And then you should set your `UICollectionView`'s layout, like:

```
CustomCollectionViewLayout * customLayout = [[CustomCollectionViewLayout alloc] init];
self.collectionView = [[UICollectionView alloc] initWithFrame:someFrame collectionViewLayout:customLayout];
```

or like:

```
[self.collectionView setCollectionViewLayout:customLayout animated:YES];
```

Comment: i can set `UICollectionView's`layout on this method `(CGFloat)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView layout:(UICollectionViewLayout *)collectionViewLayout minimumLineSpacingForSectionAtIndex:(NSInteger)section` or which method i should set

Comment: Actually, you cannot set `UICollectionView`'s layout with that method. It is only a method of `UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout` and is used to decide `minimumLineSpacing` for a section. You can use needed `UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout` methods to decide spacings and sizes for every `section` or `indexPath`. And you can use my sample if you don't need to element-specific measures.

Comment: Also the documentation states: All of the methods in this protocol are optional. If you do not implement a particular method, the flow layout delegate uses values in its own properties for the appropriate spacing information.

The flow layout object expects the collection view’s delegate object to adopt this protocol. Therefore, implement this protocol on object assigned to your collection view’s delegate property.

Comment: the code what you write it's for 4inch screen and i must put other code for 3.5inch screen?

Comment: No, it is only used to decide `ItemSize` variable. You can also decide others, for example `minimumInteritemSpacing`, according to the screen size. I did not change others because you said that in your question: _I want to have the gaps between the edges and between cells remain the same_.

Comment: Yes; i need to remain the same for both views 4inch and 3.5inch so it'll complain for the both views?

Comment: No, there is nothing to complain about it. They can be same if you want.